# Datatables Column Hiding is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to sort a column on the base of another column. For this, I have made a column hidden in datatables but it is hiding all the values upto few rows only. I am not able to figure out what's happening in it.

Here is the working link:

[Link](http://satishsaini.com/sort/layout.html)

I am using following code to hide a column and sort another column on the basis of this hidden column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [null,null,null,null,null,null,{"bVisible": false},{"iDataSort":6},null,null]
});   
});
```